# pCloud API upload file android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, api-design, pcloud

I'm trying to use pcloud   [API from github](https://github.com/pCloud/pcloud-sdk-java)

Can some one tell me how to upload local file from phone with this api?

I found that i should use:

```
ApiClient apiClient =...;
File localFile = ...;

RemoteFile uploadedFile = apiClient.createFile(
    RemoteFolder.ROOT_FOLDER_ID,
    localFile.getName(),
    DataSource.create(localFile),
    new Date(localFile.lastModified())
        .execute();
```

Im alredy managed to add apikey and login with oauth.
But i dont known how to add storage path to this code.

> ApiClient apiClient =...; File localFile = ...;

Sorry for my english is not my primary language.
I will be very 
grateful if someone can help me. Im 
beginner in coding and still learning

Comment: Have you read about [Creating a Client](https://github.com/pCloud/pcloud-sdk-java#creating-a-client)?

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand . If some one can give me examples how to use it I will be greatefu

Comment: Well, I've had no experience with this before, but if you start from [Register your pCloud API application](https://github.com/pCloud/pcloud-sdk-java#1-register-your-pcloud-api-application) and read it carefully, it looks like you'd be able to start up in a few hours

Comment: I alredy connect  nad Register your pCloud API application but don't known how to use  upload/download code

Comment: Well, like I told you, my experience here is null. So I wish you find the answer you're looking for and hopefully reply here if you do, in case someone else have the same problem